# calculate circumference with given radius

Tags: javascript, geometry

I am trying to calculate and display the circumference by retrieving the already defined radius from the given code of a drawn circle. Is it the way I typed out the formula wrong or does it need to be in the same script section?

```js
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('circle');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var X = canvas.width / 2;
    var Y = canvas.height / 2;
    var R = 45;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, R, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function calculatecircumference() {
  var circumference = ((2) * (Math.Pi) * (R));
}

document.getElementById("Circumference").innerHTML = circumference;
```

```html
<!Doctype>
<html>

<body onload="draw();">
  <canvas id="circle" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
</body>

<p>Circumference: <span id="Circumference"></span></p>

</html>
```

Comment: what is the current result..and what is the expected ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: I"m expecting it to display the circumference and the current result shows nothing but the circle.

Comment: Your variable `R` is defined in a different function, and is therefore not visible inside `calculatecircumference()`. Declare it as global. Same goes for `circumference`. Also that line that sets the `innerHTML` needs to be inside the function.

Comment: The problem isn't that `document.getElementById("Circumference")`, but rather that the variable `circumference` is defined inside a function that is never called. Same with `calculatecircumference()` not having scope to see the variable `R` defined in `draw()`.

Comment: should the circum be equal to 282.74 ?

Comment: @ObsidianAge The DOM issue is still a valid issue. Before your edit, the `<script>` was directly above the `<p>` that the `document.getElementById` call was trying to find immediately.

Comment: @BeckySue Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: @BeckySue did that work ????????????

Answer (score 0):

Actually the math PI is wrong....you have  written **Math.Pi**

```
var circumference = ((2) * (Math.Pi) * (R));
```

but in actual it is **Math.PI**

```
var circumference = ((2) * (Math.PI) * (R));
```

Hence it Returns a *NaN* for a radius of 45 ..

Check the working below code.... also you need to call the calculatecircumference function..and pass the Radius as param

```js
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('circle');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var X = canvas.width / 2;
    var Y = canvas.height / 2;
    var R = 45;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, R, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
    ctx.stroke();
 calculatecircumference(R);
  }
}

function calculatecircumference(R) {
  var circumference = ((2) * (Math.PI) * (R));
    
document.getElementById("Circumference").innerHTML = circumference;

}
```

```html
<body onload="draw();">
  <canvas id="circle" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
</body>

<p>Circumference: <span id="Circumference"></span></p>
```

Comment: you are missing the chain...  call calculatecircumference within the draw,,,and call the insertion with in calculatecircumference ....

Comment: a chain of events calling each another ...hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems:

- First, you need to give `calculatecircumference()` scope to access `R`. This can be done by calling `calculatecircumference()` from within `draw()` and passing it through as a function parameter. You'll also need to tell `calculatecircumference()` that its function parameter should be assigned to the local variable `R`, by writing it as `calculatecircumference(R)`.
- Second, `document.getElementById("Circumference").innerHTML` does not have access to the scope of `circumference`. Simply run the line `document.getElementById("Circumference").innerHTML = circumference` line inside `caluclatecircumference()`.
- Finally, you called `Math.Pi` instead of `Math.PI` in `calculatecircumference()`. The `PI` *must* be uppercase.

Correcting these three issues fixes the problem, as can be seen below:

```js
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('circle');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var X = canvas.width / 2;
    var Y = canvas.height / 2;
    var R = 45;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, R, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
    ctx.stroke();
    calculatecircumference(R);
  }
}

function calculatecircumference(R) {
  var circumference = ((2) * (Math.PI) * (R));
  document.getElementById("Circumference").innerHTML = circumference;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype>
<html>

<body onload="draw();">
  <canvas id="circle" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
</body>

<p>Circumference: <span id="Circumference"></span></p>

</html>
```

Hope this helps! :)